# VSCode - You don't have an extension for debugging c# error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

it's my first time trying out vscode on a linux system (manjaro xfce).

But when i try to debug a simple c# hello world program, it tells me that i am missing the extension for c#, although the extension IS installed. i already tried to reinstall the extension or reinstall vscode but nothing helped... You can see the error on my screenshot.

I already tried to google the error and watched setup videos on youtube but somehow nobody has this problem. Am i doing something wrong? Pls help... [image]

Btw. when I try to generate assets by the command pallet it tells me that the omnisharp is not running. I am so fking confused...

Thx in advance

Comment: Select 'Run', then 'Debug', then click Create a `launch.json` if prompted

Comment: When I select run and then debug i get prompted that message you see on my screenshot.

Comment: Do you see anything in the 'Output' section of VS Code?

Comment: nothing new when i click on debug. but at the start of the program it checks omniserver and some other things.

Answer (score 0):

If running and debugging is not yet configured (no launch.json has been created), VS Code shows the Run start view:

[image: Run & Debug Panel]

VS Code will try to automatically detect your debug environment, but if this fails, you will have to choose it manually:
[image: Select Environment Dropdown List]

Comment: i clicked on create a launch.json file and it created one with this code: {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
} 

but i dont know where to select the debug the environment. where do i do that??

Comment: If you don't have to select the environment, it means it automatically selected it for you. Can you try running the program?

Comment: Nope, it still gives me the same error, that i dont have the c# extension.

Comment: Delete the 'vscode' folder in your directory, then go to the command dropdown by pressing 'F1' and enter the following: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'. If that doesn't help, try checking out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: generate assets gave me following error: Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated.